# Magento 2: I want to clone the Media folder as well while cloning the Magento 2 GIT repository

Tags: magento2, media, git, folder, github

How can I clone the Media folder while cloning the Magento 2 GIT repository?

Comment: Make sure media folder exist at git repo and you don't have pub/media in .gitiignore

Answer (score 2):

For this you can open git repo url and check if media folder is available in git repository ? 
If not available than ask administrator to commit in new branch and you can take a pull of that branch.

Some time, it can also be in git ignore file which will be hidden file .gitignore

check if this exist in that file "/.media"

than its confirmed that its ignored in git list.

Comment: I already updated the gitignore file....but still media folder not coming

Answer (score 0):

open your git repository url and check if media folder exist in git repo ?